# Limiting the number of characters you can enter into a Windows Forms textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Assuming that I have a Windows Forms textbox and want to reduce the maximum amount of characters that can be allowed in via user entry, how would I do that?

Comment: Is this textbox located in an ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone 7, Console, Zune, XBox 360 or other type of application? You have only used the `vb.net` which is a programming language allowing to develop all those kind of applications in which we have textboxes, and obviously limiting the number of characters that one might type would differ.

Comment: Whoops, I totally forgot to mention that, I apologize, I will edit the OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the MaxLength property.  No code required, you can set it in the designer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx) property to set the maximum number of characters allowed in a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Set MaxLength does not work with isNumber=true, you still can input 00012 regardless of limit = 4

My solution:

```
Protected Overridable Sub szSeqNmbr_KeyPress(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal    eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles szAuthID.KeyPress
    Dim KeyAscii As Short = Convert.ToInt32(eventArgs.KeyChar)

    If (szAuthID.Text.Length >= szAuthID.MaxLength) Then
        'szAuthID.Text = szAuthID.Text.Substring(0, szAuthID.MaxLength)
        If (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) Then
            eventArgs.Handled = True
            Return
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```